# OAuth2 IMAP access to GMail service account

Tags: email, oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-imap

I'm trying to migrate working Java app accessing Gmail account via IMAP protocol from username/password authentication to OAuth2 (currently the app is working with "Enable less secure apps" enabled).

I started with downloading JSON key from Google console for my service account and managed to get an access token:

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
    new FileInputStream("my-account.json"))
    .createScoped(Collections.singletonList("https://mail.google.com/"));

AccessToken accessToken = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
System.out.println(accessToken.getTokenValue());
        System.out.println(accessToken.getTokenValue());
```

This creates access token which I'm able to validate by visiting https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=

Response is:

```
{
  "issued_to": "XXXX",
  "audience": "XXXX",
  "scope": "https://mail.google.com/",
  "expires_in": 3588,
  "access_type": "online"
}
```

Problem happens when I try to access IMAP account with this access token.
Each time I get **lookup failed**. Here is detailed JavaMail log:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK Gimap ready for requests from [REMOVED_LOCAL_IP] b8mb121231068edr
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=OAUTHBEARER AUTH=XOAUTH
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! b8mb121231068edr
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: OAUTHBEARER
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=imap.gmail.com, user=etmfdev@etmf-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: mechanism PLAIN disabled by property: mail.imap.auth.plain.disable
DEBUG IMAP: mechanism LOGIN disabled by property: mail.imap.auth.login.disable
DEBUG IMAP: mechanism NTLM disabled by property: mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable
A1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 [REMOVED_BASE64_ENCODED_USER_PLUS_TOKEN]
+ eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
[REMOVED_BASE64_ENCODED_USER_PLUS_TOKEN]
A1 NO Lookup failed b8mb121231068edr
```

This Base64 encoded part starting with eyJZ says this:

```
{"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}
```

Any ideas what might be the root cause? Is the problem in Google account setup or in the code I'm using?

Java code used is this

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
    new FileInputStream("my-account.json"))
    .createScoped(Collections.singletonList("https://mail.google.com/"));

AccessToken accessToken = credentials.refreshAccessToken();

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.xoauth2.disable", "false");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
session.setDebug(true);
Store store = session.getStore("imap");

store.connect("imap.gmail.com", imapEmailAddress, accessToken.getTokenValue());
```

Comment: Did you grant domain-wide authority to the Service Account and impersonate the user?

Comment: One thing I've tried in the meantime is changing imapEmailAddress from client_email mentioned in the JSON file (the one ending with ...iam.gserviceaccount.com) to the email with custom domain used previously with username/password authentication. In that case I simply get 'A1 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)' instead of Lookup failed.

Comment: I have 'Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation' turned on.

Comment: I'm thinking you might be missing the impersonation step. Try adding `.createDelegated("email-adress-to-impersonate");` when building the credentials (that is, just after `.createScoped`).

Comment: After adding .createDelegated("my-email"), I get this 'java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: 401 Unauthorized
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'. Line credentials.refreshAccessToken() throws this exception.

Comment: Are you sure the account you are trying to access is part of your domain?

Comment: I'm trying to access Inbox of the same service account used to login to Google console.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand `the same service account used to login to Google console`. Service Accounts don't have access to UI, like Google Console. They are not regular accounts. How did you create this Service Account? If you want to access the Service Account inbox, and not impersonate another account, you don't need DWD. Also, I see that you did check `'Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation'`, but that by itself is not enough to grant DWD. You then have to follow [these steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority).

Comment: Hi Igor, I'm just wondering if you ever got this working? Regards Andrew